# how to ensure there single edge in a graph for a given order_id?

Tags: graph, unique, titan, gremlin, edges

My current scenario is like I have I have **products**,**customer** and **seller** nodes in my graph ecosystem. The problem I am facing is that I have to ensure uniqueness of

> `(customer)-[buys]->product`

with **order_item_id** as property of the **buys** relation edge.I have to ensure that there is an unique edge with buys property for a given order_item_id. In this way I want to ensure that my graph insertion remains idempotent and no repeated buys edges are created for a given order_item_id.

creating a order_item_id property

```
if(!mgmt.getPropertyKey("order_item_id")){
    order_item_id=mgmt.makePropertyKey("order_item_id").dataType(Integer.class).make();
}else{
    order_item_id=mgmt.getPropertyKey("order_item_id");
}
```

What I have found so far is that building unique index might solve my problem. like

```
if(mgmt.getGraphIndex('order_item_id')){
    ridIndexBuilder=mgmt.getGraphIndex('order_item_id')
}else{
    ridIndexBuilder=mgmt.buildIndex("order_item_id",Edge.class).addKey(order_item_id).unique().buildCompositeIndex();
}
```

Or I can also use something like

> `mgmt.buildEdgeIndex(graph.getOrCreateEdgeLabel("product"),"uniqueOrderItemId",Direction.BOTH,order_item_id)`

- How should I ensure this uniqueness of single buys edge for a given
  order_item_id. (I don't have a use-case to search based on
  order_item_id.)
- What is the basic difference in creating an index on edge using
  **buildIndex** and using **buildEdgeIndex**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot enforce the uniqueness of properties at the edge-level, ie. between two vertices (see [this question on the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/aureliusgraphs/aFiJR0Vx8uI/discussion)). If I understand your problem correctly, building a `CompositeIndex` on edge with a uniqueness constraint for a given property should address your problem, even though you do not plan to search these edges by the indexed property. However, this could lead to performance issues when inserting many edges simultaneously due to locking. Depending on the rate at which you insert data, you may have to skip the locking (= skip the uniqueness constraint) and risk duplicate edges, then handle the deduplication yourself at read time and/or run post-import batch jobs to clean up potential duplicates.

- `buildIndex()` builds a global, graph-index (either `CompositeIndex` or `MixedIndex`). These kind of indexes typically allows you to quickly find starting points of your `Traversal` within a graph.
- However, `buildEdgeIndex()` allows you to build a local, "[vertex-centric index](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/indexes.html#vertex-indexes)" which is meant to speed-up the traversal between vertices with a potentially [high degree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_(graph_theory)#Types_of_vertices) (= huge number of incident edges, incoming and/or outgoing). Such vertices are called "super nodes" (see [A solution to the supernode problem blog post from Aurelius](https://thinkaurelius.com/2012/10/25/a-solution-to-the-supernode-problem/)) - and although they tend to be quite rare, the likelihood of traversing them isn't that low.

Reference: [Titan documentation, Ch. 8 - Indexing for better Performance](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/indexes.html).

Comment: thanks yet again for detailed info .are performance issues so severe that we can skip locking and put database consistency at stake? Is there a performance drawback even when I dont need realtime results from titan db? will heavy locking insertions have impact on read queries?

Comment: The performance concern really depends on the size of the graph and rate at which you insert data. At scale, you will most likely always want to avoid locking in order to preserve fast write performance. If you're really concerned about speed, I think it's best to set up a performance test, with and without locking, and see what kind of read and write performance you get.

Comment: I came up with pre-insertion check which helped me skip building index on the edges.It checks the existence of particular edge before creating it. still I am not able to digest letting go of locks for the sake of speed.(may be my ACID roots.). I think the overhead of post import job will be big. Is letting go of locks also acceptable in case of  vertex insertion?