# How to add unique constraints to edge property in janusgraph?

Tags: java, spring-boot, janusgraph, tinkerpop3, gremlin-server

How to add unique constraints to edge property in janusgraph Globally?

Unique constraints are applied to only vertex?

Comment: May be this post could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37370621/how-to-ensure-there-single-edge-in-a-graph-for-a-given-order-id